# Xcode comment keybinding is different from my settings

Tags: xcode, comments, shortcut

This is a fresh install of Xcode on my MacBook. The shortcut (keybinding) for the "Structure - Comment Selection" used to comment my code is different from the settings.
The result is that I cannot comment my code using ***CMD*** + ***/***   but I have to use ***CMD*** + ***'***
I cannot get used to that. 
Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I have a similar problem, but in my case it's CMD + Ç. I guess it's using some keyboard language configuration to impact the key binding. Unfortunately I don't have the solution just yet, but the keyboard language might be a good starting point

Comment: any solution to this ? for me was woking fine but after a couple of days got broken